# Error invoking remote method 'DB_CONNECT': Error: Host 'x.x.x.x' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, load, amazon-elb

I have been trying to access a MYSQL DB on AWS using a network LB. The database is in a private subnet and i use the NLB endpoint along with username/password to connect to the DB using SQLYog.

I have been getting the following error.

Error invoking remote method 'DB_CONNECT': Error: Host 'x.x.x.x' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

I run the FLUSH HOSTS; command on the DB and then try to connect and it works. But after a lil while i get the same error again.

I have the same setup for 3 other DBs and they work fine all the time. The only difference is those 3 are MYSQL Aurora DBS, rest is all the same.

can anyone guide.

I tried adding the IP address for both the writer & reader for the MYSQL DB, but again after a little while its the same error.